# For svn, is there a way to show which files are at an older revision?

Tags: svn

Let's say the whole project is a revision 123, and now I reverted a file `some/path/foo.txt` to revision 88 by using `svn up -r 88 some/path/foo.txt`.  At this point, is there a way to show a list of files that are "not the current revision"?  `svn st` or `svn status` will only show modified files but not files that are at an older revision.

**Update:** the command

```
svn st -v | grep -v 123
```

where the `123` is the current revision seem to do the job, except we need to check for the current revision number such as `423623` first and then run the command above... and also, what if the number `123` happens to be part of a filename, then the `grep` will do an incorrect job, so if there is a better and faster way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read more carefully about `svn status` options and output. For your use-case (mixed working copy, some files are in non-HEAD revision)

```
>svn st -u
        *       24   Hello.fr.txt
        *       21   Hello.de.txt
Status against revision:     37
```